Sentry "excess events" meaning
I got a message in my sentry dashboard "You have exceeded your performance unit limit. We are dropping any excess events". Could someone tell me what this means? Will I still get any exceptions logged, or will I have to upgrade to have this feature? What does excess events mean? Thanks in advance!

It means that the account you're using exceeded the monthly quota. As per the help.sentry.io:

new events will not be accepted until the start of the next usage period.

The website mentions the following options:
Control the volume using the dashboard with

filters to block IP-ranges and
the Delete and Discard feature for individual issues.

Use the SDK to create custom filters:
Sentry.init({
  beforeSend(event) {
    // Modify the event here
    if (event.user) {
      // Don't send user's email address
      delete event.user.email;
    }
    return event;
  }
});

You can also enable spike protection:
curl https://sentry.io/api/0/organizations/{organization_id_or_slug}/spike-protections/ \
 -H 'Authorization: Bearer <auth_token>' \
 -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
 -d '{}'

Pay more money by

upgrading the plan or
activating pay on demand

